# Count missing values under specific date conditions in R

Tags: r, missing-data, lubridate, flexdashboard

**Context**

I'm helping a friend who works in the education field and one of the programs her job offers for students during the pandemic is one-on-one tutoring on Zoom. They have employees that take attendance in a Google Sheet but inevitably sometimes they forget to mark attendance. To help her reconcile this problem, I'm trying to figure out some R code that will catch when employees forget to mark attendance. I've Googled  and attempted if_else commands, pivot_longer, for-loops, etc, but I'm still a (functional) beginner at R so a lot of what I'm reading is going over my head. (FYI R is the only programming language I know so the solution has to be something I can implement and troubleshoot in the future if need be). That said, apologies in advance for not including reproducible code (because I can't even figure out where to start). But for anyone who's able to help, [here is sample data in a publicly viewable Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QJyj-4Ap1aeuomJcA2lJ1PLhbQ90SQSqZqvu469y_hc/edit?usp=sharing).

**The problem**

I need to find and/or count the NA values that occur **after** the tutoring `start_date` but  **not** the NAs that occur in the future.  You can usually tell when an employee forgot to take attendance because:

1. those NAs fall between weeks where the employee *did* remember to take attendance and
2. those NAs occur in the past but **never** before the tutoring `start date`

To help visualize this, I have highlighted in yellow *most (maybe all)* of the NAs that meet this criteria.

Since this isn't my data/my project there are certain things about it I can't change just because it's bad practice (e.g. the fact that the day of the week and the time are in the same cell).  But any solutions you have that directly help me resolve the problem are greatly appreciated.

Best,

James

**Edit for additional context**

To help monitor attendance, I'm creating a flexdashboard and the goal is to include a valueBox (or something similar) that populates the number of tutoring sessions that have NAs that aren't supposed to. If the program administrator knows there are NAs via the dashboard, she can follow up with her employees asap and have them input the correct code (X, 1, 2, etc.). The problem she's having now is that several days or weeks can pass by and the employee may forget if the session occurred or if someone was late. Thanks!

> `dput(fake_tutoring_data)`

```
structure(list(start_date = structure(c(18893, 18897, 18898, 
18900, 18900, 18900, 18901, 18904, 18907, 18911, 18911, 18912, 
18913, 18919, 18919, 18925, 18925, 18933, 18933, 18934, 18935, 
18939, 18939, 18939, 18946, 18964, 18968, 18968), class = "Date"), 
    day_time = c("TH/7pm", "MON/5:30 PM", "TUE/6:15PM", "TH/9am", 
    "TH/6:30 PM", "TH/7pm", "F/5:15pm", "MON/4:30PM", "TH/6 pm", 
    "MON/ 5:00 PM", "MON/6:00 PM", "TUE/6:30 PM", "WED/6pm", 
    "TUE/11:00 AM", "TUE/2pm", "MON 4:45 PM", "TUE/6:00 PM", 
    "TUE/6:00 PM", "TUE/6:15PM", "WED/5:00 PM", "TH/6PM", "MON/5:30PM", 
    "MON/5:30 PM", "MON/6:00 PM", "MON/6:00 PM", "F/12pm", "Tue/ 4:30pm", 
    "Tue/5:00 pm"), `2021-09-20` = c("1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2021-09-27` = c(NA, "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2021-10-04` = c("X", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "X", NA, "1", "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `2021-10-11` = c("X", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
    "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", NA, "4", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2021-10-18` = c("X", "1", "1", 
    "1", "X", "1", "1", "1", "4", "3", "X", "1", "2", NA, "1", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2021-10-25` = c("1", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "4/5", "1", "1", "2", "X", "1", "4", 
    "1", "1", "X", "1", "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), `2021-11-01` = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", NA, 
    "1", "4", "1", "X", "1", "1", NA, "1", "1", "4", "1", "1", 
    "1", "1", "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2021-11-08` = c("1", 
    "1", "3", NA, "1", NA, "1", "X", NA, "5", NA, "4", "2", "4", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), `2021-11-15` = c("1", "1", NA, "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", 
    "2", "3", NA, "2", "4", "2", NA, "2", "1", "1", NA, NA, "1", 
    "2", "1", "1", "1", NA, NA, NA), `2021-11-22` = c(NA, "1", 
    "1", NA, NA, NA, "1", "X", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "5", "X", 
    "4", "4", "1", "4", NA, "1", "1", "2", "X", NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), `2021-11-29` = c("1", "1", NA, "1", "1", "X", "1", NA, 
    "2", NA, NA, "1", NA, "1", "2", "X", "1", "1", NA, "1", "4", 
    "1", "1", "1", "1", "4", NA, NA), `2021-12-06` = c("1", NA, 
    "1", NA, NA, NA, "5", NA, "1", NA, NA, "1", "1", NA, NA, 
    "X", "3", "1", NA, "2", "5", NA, "1", "1", "1", "4", "1", 
    "1"), `2021-12-13` = c(NA, "1", NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "5", "5", NA, NA, NA, NA, "1", "X", "2", NA, 
    NA, "5", "1", "4", NA, NA, "1"), `2021-12-20` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2021-12-27` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-01-03` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-01-10` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-01-17` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-01-24` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-01-31` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-02-07` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-02-14` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-02-21` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-02-28` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-03-07` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-03-14` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-03-21` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-03-28` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-04-04` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-04-11` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-04-18` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-04-25` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-05-02` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-05-09` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-05-16` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-05-23` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-05-30` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `2022-06-06` = c(NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-28L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: If you could edit your question to include an R object with the sample data, that would be helpful!  The raw dataframe (or however you've imported things into R) is fine.  For example, if you're loading the table into an R dataframe called `attendance`, type `dput(attendance)` in your R console and paste the result here.

Comment: Thank you for the tip and for being kind about it. I've included the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Pivoting your data is the way to go in this case.  Here's how I would do it.  First, convert `fake_tutoring_data` from wide to long format: replace each row with one corresponding row per date column, preserving the `start_date` and `day_time` identifiers.  I used a regular expression to identify date columns; they have the format YYYY-MM-DD.  (I've also added an `id` column, which is just the row number; that comes in handy later.)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

long_tutoring_data = fake_tutoring_data %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = matches("^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$"),
               names_to = "attendance_date",
               values_to = "attendance") %>%
  mutate(attendance_date = ymd(attendance_date))
```

Next, find missing attendance records by using three criteria: a record is missing if it's

1. before today,
2. on or after the corresponding `start_date`, and
3. missing.

```
missing_attendance = long_tutoring_data %>%
  filter(attendance_date < Sys.Date(),
         attendance_date >= start_date,
         is.na(attendance))
```

I haven't checked whether this corresponds exactly to the NAs you marked in the spreadsheet, but some spot-checking suggests it's pretty close.

The alternative criterion you suggested - that a missing record is one that falls chronologically between two non-missing records - is trickier but doable.  I added two columns, `previous_attendance` and `next_attendance`, that contain the previous (or next) non-null attendance record for this `id`.  Then we can find missing records that have at least one preceding and following non-missing record.

```
missing_attendance = long_tutoring_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(id, attendance_date) %>%
  mutate(previous_attendance = attendance,
         next_attendance = attendance) %>%
  fill(previous_attendance, .direction = "down") %>%
  fill(next_attendance, .direction = "up") %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(is.na(attendance),
         !is.na(previous_attendance),
         !is.na(next_attendance))
```

This doesn't identify as many missing records as the first method; you'll be the best judge of which method is more accurate for your purposes.

Comment: You may in that case accept the answer as the answer to your question by clicking on the checkmark.